# Spring class-loading issues while deploying EAR application on WebSphere 9

Tags: java, spring, maven, websphere, spring-aop

I have tried to deploy and run application on WebShphere Java 8 . I have posted similar question here and in IBM forum too. I didn't get a solution yet . Myself  i tried lot of methods to solve this error . I have updated that methods with this question .

When i try to deploy and run the application , i am getting following exception error .

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: 
Exception caught while initializing context: {0} java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:141)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:130)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:258)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplicationContext.<clinit>(JavassistApplicationContext.java:61)
        ... 114 more
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1120)
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1063)
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1021)
        at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1259)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplicationContext.<clinit>(JavassistApplicationContext.java:59)
        ... 114 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:346)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:283)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass2(ClassPool.java:1133)
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1114)
        ... 118 more
```

This is my parent pom.xml file

```
<groupId>com.webapp.ss</groupId>
    <artifactId>ss-parent</artifactId>

  <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- spring (former acegi) security -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.wsit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.wsit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wsit-rt</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.16</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
                <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.snmp4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>snmp4j</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.snmp4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>snmp4j-agent</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcaptcha</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.5</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                        <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.8</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
                <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.8</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>jfree</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.15</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jfree</groupId>
                <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.samba.jcifs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.6</version>
            </dependency>





            <dependency>
                <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
                <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>am-client</groupId>
                <artifactId>am-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${project.basedir}/am-client.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>[1.1.1,)</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>[1.0.3,)</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>       
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showDeprecation>${maven.compiler.showDeprecation}</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>${maven.compiler.showWarnings}</showWarnings>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <debug>${maven.compiler.debug}</debug>
                    <optimize>${maven.compiler.optimize}</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </build

  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-ws.version>2.4.0.RELEASE</spring-ws.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <slf4jVersion>1.6.1</slf4jVersion>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
        <hibernate.version>3.5.6-Final</hibernate.version>
   </properties>
```

and the child pom.xml file

```
<groupId>com.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>tt-parent</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

i am using spring `4.2.5.RELEASE` version and javassist `3.19.0-GA` version . maven java 1.8 source and target

```
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
```

and 
and my maven dependencies tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ app-webapp ---
[INFO] com.myapp:app-webapp:war:6.2.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.19.0-GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.46:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] \- com.ibm:ibmpkcs:jar:8.0:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Enterprise Application packge
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ app-ear ---
[INFO] com.myapp:app-ear:ear:6.2.0
[INFO] +- com.myapp:app-webapp:war:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:provided
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] \- com.ibm:ibmpkcs:jar:8.0:compile
```

I think i am facing any class loader issues . i have enabled verbose class loading too in websphere .

I have removed the class files from `/WEB-INF/classes/org/springframework/aop/framework` in order to avoid any class loading but still i am getting the same exception error. Is this really due to class loading issue ? or any other issues ?

Any help and suggestion ? Is it any spring issues here ?

**Update :**

Also tried class loader parent last method on server and application

Comment: Anyone has suggestion ?